# Gradient of the energy functional in $H^{1,2}$-norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, morse-theory

I have to use estimates for the gradient of the energy functional on the free loop space of a fixed compact manifold $Q$. As such, one considers $H^{1,2}$-maps of the circle into $Q$. The energy functional is given by
$\mathcal{E}:H^{1,2}(S^1,Q)\rightarrow IR ,\quad \gamma\mapsto \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\|\dot{\gamma}(t)\|^2dt$. Is there a neat formula for the gradient w.r.t. the $H^{1,2}$ inner product?

Comment: This is a straightforward computation that you should do yourself. But what does "neat" mean here?

Comment: The computation is straightforward w.r.t. $L^2$, not $H^{1,2}$.

Comment: I only know of a variational characterization, i.e. in terms of an ODE, but no "explicit" form.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that there should be an explicit formula?